# how to post data from method of conroller in opencart2.x this example?

Tags: javascript, php, html, opencart2.x

i want to create new method in class `ControllerCatalogMproduct` in opencart2.x
but i dont know do send data from `mproduct_form.tpl` when click save button to controller .

```
    <div id="content">
      <div class="page-header">
        <div class="container-fluid">
          <div class="pull-right"> 
<button type="submit" form="form-mproduct" data-toggle="tooltip" title="<?php echo $button_save; ?>" class="btn btn-primary"><i class="fa fa-save"></i></button>
            <a href="<?php echo $cancel; ?>" data-toggle="tooltip" title="<?php echo $button_cancel; ?>" class="btn btn-default"><i class="fa fa-reply"></i></a></div>
          <h1><?php echo $heading_title; ?></h1>
          <ul class="breadcrumb">
            <?php foreach ($breadcrumbs as $breadcrumb) { ?>
            <li><a href="<?php echo $breadcrumb['href']; ?>"><?php echo $breadcrumb['text']; ?></a></li>
            <?php } ?>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </div>
```

I have come to the question how when click the `button with type submit` without `javascript` and `jquery`,send post to `controller` and save in `db`!!!

when click or edit button in main page and update url to example:
`http://www.example.com/admin/index.php?route=catalog/mproduct/edit&token=N3bmdZW8C&productid=67`

whats mean `$("form[id*='form-']").submit();`?